# The control didnt' hide even the script is run

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have 2 panels on aspx pages. When the page is load, the step1 panel is shown. After the user click the button. I check the data and show the step2 panel in which I show the data into repeater control in code behind. There is a "Back" button. When user clicks this button, I need to hide the step 2 panel and show the step1 panel again. My problem is when the user click the back button. I can see the step1 is shown but gone then the step2 panel is still there.  Would someone help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

There is my aspx page:

```xml
<asp:panel id="pnlStep1" runat="server" visible="False"  >   
<asp:label id="lbl" text="The order is ....."/> 
  <asp:Button id="btnNext" runat="server" text="Next" cssclass="btn"/>
</asp:panel>

<asp:panel id="pnlStep2" runat="server" visible="False"  >            
  <fieldset class="fldBoxy"><legend class="fldLegend">Conflicts</legend>
    <table class="tbl w100p" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="field100">
          <asp:repeater id="repConflicts" runat="server" >
            <itemtemplate>
              <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Details") %>
              <br/>
            </itemtemplate>
          </asp:repeater>
          <asp:label id="lblNoConflicts" runat="server" visible="False" text="No conflicts were found."></asp:label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="savechanges">
    <table class="w100p" >
      <tr>
        <td class="talgnL" ><asp:Button ID="btnBack"  Text="Back" runat="server" CssClass="btn" OnClientClick="hideStep2()"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:Button id="btnSave" runat="server" text="  Change" cssclass="btn"  />
         <input class=" btn" onclick="self.close();" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</asp:panel>
```

There is my javascritp:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function hideStep2(){
    var pln = document.getElementById("pnlStep2");
    if (pln != 'undefined') {
      alert('24');                   
      pln.style.visibility = "hidden";
      pln.style.display = "none";   
      document.getElementById("pnlStep1").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: try to comment `pln.style.visibility = "hidden";`

Comment: You have a rogue `disableafterclick="True">` which is not contained in any tag

Comment: @Verdolino. there is cut and paste mistake. I edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems an unusual way of doing it. Without seeing your backend code, I'm only guessing but this can all be done server side.

Change panel1 to visible=true, and then use the onclick event on the button to switch it to false, and panel2 to true.

Then use onclick event on the back button to switch panel1 to visible=true, and panel2 to false.

This means there is no need for any javascript.

Comment: @Jamestbr, I already applied the way on vb to set the switch panel1 to visible=true, and panel2 to false. However there is a large space in the popup window by using this way.

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean. If a control is set to visible="false", then it is not rendered on the browser, so it wouldn't cause any large empty space. Have you considered using the asp.net Wizard control for this kind of logic?